# android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

Tags: android, android-layout, findviewbyid

Myactivity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Button bt;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        bt= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_1);
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/edittext"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/bt_1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have the following questions(intellij IDEA):

1. When I chage the layout relative position:Button up,EditText down,the problem is solved;else the problem come again!
2. When delect the code"bt= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_1);"the problem is solved.

[image: the logcat description follows]

Comment: when you got this problem when your button in xml is above edit text ?

Comment: Before running the project, have you tried clean building the project first?

Comment: i think your code here is working pretty well , but i dont understand when you get this error?

Comment: For other users reference, here is the image url (since the image appears small and hard to read here): http://i.stack.imgur.com/IiWrG.png

Comment: yeap.I have clean the project through intellij--Analyze--code cleanup--whole projet before running.

Comment: when I got this proble,my button in xml is below the edittext.

Comment: with relative layout or with linear ?

Comment: can you post code that you got these error exactly ? Because i try to move button below edittext and it working fine..

Comment: **Please copy and paste the entire stacktrace into the question, as external images aren't search-engine friendly and might go stale in time.**

Comment: I have solved the problem in a stupid way.Just opened a new program and clicked the whole codes again.then the problem disappeared.I didnot know why.But thank you so much.